# Why do many C functions require the size of one of its arguments?

Tags: c, pointers

Lets say we have the following functions:

```
char buffer[BUFFER_LENGTH];
//...
struct sockaddr_in cli_addr;
socklen_t clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
int newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
read(newsockfd, buffer, 255);
```

Why do these functions require the length of one of their arguments? Wouldn't be possible to just use sizeof operator and remove the length argument? For example;

```
int accept(int socketfd, struc sockaddr * socketaddr) {
    int sockaddrlen = sizeof(*sockaddr); // sizeof sockaddr instance in memory
    // rest of the function
}

void read(int fd, char* buffer) {
    int messageLength = sizeof(*buffer);
    // rest of the function
}
```

Or, instead do like this:

```
void read(int fd, char* buffer) {
    read(fd, buffer, sizeof(*buffer);
}
```

Isn't that possible? Why not?

Comment: There is no language C/C++. C and C++ are different languages, pick one.

Comment: This is presumably to allow the size of `sockaddr_in` to change in later versions. In that case `sizeof(sockaddr_in)` would have different values in existing compiled binaries. If you pass in the size to the implementation it can remain backward compatible.

Comment: C++ doesn't need that, it has `std::vector`.

Comment: `struct sockaddr` has a different size then `struct sockaddr_in` then `struct sockaddr_un` then ...

Comment: Get a good C++ book to learn the language. Don't use youtube or other tutorials of questionable origin (and I include the CS50 course). They will not give you the whole picture - worse: almost all of them are flawed at best, many are even wrong and teach bad coding style.

Comment: Here `void read(int fd, char* buffer) {
    read(fd, buffer, sizeof(*buffer); ...` `*buffer` evaluates to a `char`. The size of a `char` is 1.

Answer (score 4):

Because (at least in C) arrays are decayed into pointers (notably when passed as arguments).

So when you code `sizeof(*buffer)` you mean the same as `sizeof(char)` which is 1 by definition.

C is not the same as C++; in genuine C++, you almost never use raw arrays (but [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container)), and you would for example pass a `std::vector<char>& vc` to your hypothetical `read` (and then, you would use `vc.size()` inside it).

Notice that C (but not C++) accepts [flexible array members](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member). You certainly could code a library using them systematically (and adopt some convention about getting the allocated size thru some non-last member in `struct`-s ending with such a flexible array member)....

BTW `sizeof` is always a constant (even for `struct`-s ended with a flexible array member), except when applied to [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)-s

Comment: In case of struct having no-array members, ´sizeof(thatStruct)´ would be always the same, while having array member ´sizeof(thatStruct)´ could be different depending on the flexible array size. Is that what you mean?